# Creating multiple instances of xml android layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, arraylist

hope you fine and well,

i have the following XML layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="406dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

simply, it contains Textview and Image view.

and i have the following function which receive an arraylist as follows:

```
  public void DisplyOnTextView(List< Student > students) {
        textView.setText(students.get(i).getDes());
        new LoadImage().execute(students.get(i).getUrl().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
}
```

what i want to do is to loop in the received (students) array list to create a new instance of the xml layout which will contain a textview and imageview for each student in the array then to store each layout in array like this :

```
int[] layouts = {R.layout.instance1, R.layout.instance2,...};
```

my loop will look like :

```
for(int i=0;i<students.size(); i++){
// create new layout for student[i]
// create new textview for student[i]
//create new imageview for student[i]
// layouts[i] = the new created layout 
}
```

is this possible? 
any help ?!

regards..

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do, but have a look at `ListView` with custom adapter

Answer (score 3):

you can declare your custom view, and make it extend RelativeLayout, and in it's constructor you will call

```
inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_xml, this);
```

then you can instanciate your custom view and put it as a child in any other ViewGroup

you can even do your stuff in this custom view, like making a method to display your data ... for example

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout{

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private TextView tv;
    private ImageView iv;

    private void init(){
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_xml, this);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        iv = findViewById((R.id.textView); // your imageview id is textview !!?
    }

    public void drawStudent(Student student){
        textView.setText(student.getDes());
        new LoadImage().execute(student.getUrl().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
    }
}
```

then you can use this view from your Activity like :

```
CustomView[] layouts = new CustomView[students.size()];

for(int i=0;i<students.size(); i++){
// create new layout for student[i]
CustomView v = new CustomView(this);

// layouts[i] = the new created layout 
layouts[i] = v;

}
```

you can then add these views to any ViewGroup through :

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)findViewById(...);
v.addChild(layouts[0]);
layouts[0].drawStudent(students.get(i));
```

hope this helped

NOTE : this code is just a sample, but it is not tested and not guaranteed, it is just the ideas of how to do it

UPDATE - to use XML directly :

in your loop you can do as follows :

```
ViewGroup[] layouts = new ViewGroup[students.size()];

LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());    
for(int i=0;i<students.size(); i++){
// create new layout for student[i]
ViewGroup v = i.inflate(R.layout.your_xml,null); // you can use RelativeLayout instead of ViewGroup since your root view is RelativeLayout

// setup textView
TextView tv = (TextView) v.getChildAt(1) // child view at index 1
tv.setText(...);

// setup imageView
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.getChildAt(2) // child view at index 2
new ImageLoader.....

// layouts[i] = the new created layout 
layouts[i] = v;

}
```

Comment: thank you dear, i cant understand it clearly, all what i need is to create a new layout like the xml file and a new textview and imageview for each student then to store them inside the layouts array .. all this need to be done inside the for loop .. i didn't understand the concept of your code ..

Comment: you are welcome, and sorry if my answer was not clear, what i meant to say is that it is possible if you used a CustomView that represents your xml layout ... if you want to use xml directlyt, you may need to inflate the xml file every time in the loop and assign it to a RelativeLayout in your loop, and access it's childs to set them (TextView and ImageView) then add this RelativeLayout to the ViewGroup that will display them ... but not sure of this

Comment: thanks again, maybe the second idea is what i mean , but how this can be done ?!! any reference or sample ?!

Comment: you are welcome, i updated the answer, but please notice i did not run the code to test it, it is just the ideas